# Optimal indexing for SELECT (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database-design, index-tuning

What indexes would you recommend for the following select (and why)? Keep in mind there can be tens of millions of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE md5 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ? LIMIT 200
```

Where:

- **md5** = CHAR(32)
- **created_at** = DATETIME

The question is: what indexes would you add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1

Based on the `WHERE` clause, I highly recommend a compound index

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX (md5,created_at);
```

That way, all parts of the `WHERE` clause are answered by the index.

## SUGGESTION #2

Since you are imposing a limit of 200, collect the 200 keys first, then join the keys

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT id FROM mytable
    WHERE md5 = ?
    AND created_at >= ?
    AND created_at <= ? LIMIT 200
) A INNER JOIN mytable B USING (id);
```

I have suggested [this technique before in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983156/fetching-a-single-row-from-join-table/6023217#6023217)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: BTW don't worry about not having an `ORDER BY` clause. The order of retrieval is imposed by the index.

Answer (score 1):

Go for md5(15) because it has better cardinality and `ref` always beats `range` in performance.

You wrote `LIMIT 200` without ordering clause. Just heads up.